# How i can work on same branch but exclude few files in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, centos

I have one branch named `john` which i am working in my office.
Now i want to work from home so i have cloned the`repo`. Now as my home computer has different settings so there are files like

`settings,test1, test2 , test3` etc which i don't to track on my home computer. I want to work on same branch as `john` and i want to commit to same branch as well.

How can i choose which branch i have to work.  and how to ignore those files

Answer (score 0):

- Enable MQ extension
- Store skeleton files in repository
- Add location-specific edits to files as MQ-patches in repositories

Answer (score 0):

I tend to keep default files in the repo, ones which don't actually work but don't interfere with the code that's in use. e.g. instead of having a file called settings in your repo, I'd have one called settings.default

This can be kept safely in your repos and be populated with example data. Then when you clone a repo to a new location or machine you just copy the settings.default file to settings and add your location specific data.

You would ignore the plain settings file in .hgignore so it never gets pushed between repos.